# How can I programmatically know if a NSTextField is currently displaying a placeholder ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I programmatically know if a NSTextField is currently displaying a placeholder ?

In other terms, if a placeholder has been assigned to it... ?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the method:

```
- (NSString *)placeholderString
```

Returns the cell’s plain text placeholder string.

This method is declared in NSTextFieldCell and The `NSTextField` class uses the `NSTextFieldCell` class to implement its user interface:

All of the methods declared by this class are also declared by the NSTextField class, which uses NSTextFieldCell objects to draw and edit text. These NSTextField cover methods call the corresponding NSTextFieldCell methods.

Example (the placeholder must be access via the textfield's cell):

```
NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
NSString *placeHolderString = [[textField cell] placeholderString];
```

Comment: [NSTextField placeholderString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd67e260

Comment: [[field cell] placeholderString]

Comment: @Patrick Added that the cell of the textField must be accessed.